# Excel gets strange characters when importing data from Oracle DB

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I'm using an excel workbook to fill a few worksheets with data from an oracle DB. 
The connections are properly set up, however when the worksheets are refreshed, the text that has accents like '~' is replaced with '?'.
Ex: The result of the query is ' Não '. In Excel it shows ' N?o '.

Maybe the encoding isn't right however I've tried saving the workbook with UTF-8 encoding and the problem remains. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is the font **Arial Unicode MS** ??

Comment: The excel font is Calibri.

Comment: Does changing the font to **Arial Unicode MS** improve things ??

Comment: It did not. Could it be an ODBC setting or something? Maybe out of excel..because when I do the query in SQL Developer everything is okay.

Comment: It's a stretch, but have you tried querying then pasting into Excel to see if characters are maintained?

Comment: Which Excel version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lied within NLS_LANG.

The environment variable was missing and the solution was adding it with the right value. As soon as I added it, when I tried refreshing the connection in excel everything worked fine.
In my case the value for NLS_LANG was: PORTUGUESE_PORTUGAL.WE8ISO8859P15.
However that may vary according to where you live and the regional settings of your machine.

I hope this helps other people, seeing as I've barely seen any other solutions for this online.

Comment: I'd send you to my long post about nls_lang on the OTN forum but that would be self-promotion. First thing that crossed my mind as I read your question; good thing you were able to figure it out. Check out NLS_LANG FAQ, exceptionally well written imo. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html